# Will bubbling nitric oxide through a solution of sodium percarbonate neutralize the NO?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

The sciencemadness wiki page on Nitric Oxide (https://www.sciencemadness.org/smwiki/index.php/Nitric_oxide) states that NO can be neutralized by "bubbling it in a sodium percarbonate solution". Unfortunately, no further source or information on this technique is provided.

My inexperienced guess is that the H2O2 from the dissolved sodium percarbonate oxidizes the NO to NO2, which reacts with water to form HNO3 and is finally neutralized by the carbonate ions in solution. Does this sound anywhere close to correct? However, since NO is almost insoluble in water, will bubbling with an inverted funnel trap really react with it quick enough before the bubbles reach the surface?

Finally, is there any danger to attempting this scrubbing method other than unreacted NO reaching the surface and turning into NO2 gas?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I would not say danger, but percarbonate should to be kept in excess to stop neutralisation at bicarbonate level. Otherwise evolved CO2 could be stripping out part of NO.